# Why are so many Array.prototype (iteration) methods so slow?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I decided to assess all of my for loops in my project to see if I could replace it with an `Array.prototype` method - 75% of them could easily be replaced. Before I started the replacements, I thought I might run some tests. **Most  prototype methods were significantly slower (~80%) than polyfills on my machine**.

*Each of these tests are faster with a regular for loop*

- [`Array.prototype.find` vs. for loop](https://jsperf.com/find-vs-loop)
- [`Array.prototype.concat` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/array-concat-vs-push-2/8)
- [`Array.prototype.filter` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/javascript-filter-vs-loop)
- [`Array.prorotype.forEach` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/75)
- [`Array.prototype.map` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/6)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-reduce-vs-for-loop)
- [`Array.prototype.some` vs for loop](https://jsperf.com/array-some-vs-loop)

I did not have the time to look up other jsperf tests, but i'm sure most prototype methods will be slower. **So why?** These functions are very useful, but how come they are *so much* slower than simple for loops.

Chrome 60.0.3112 / Windows 10 0.0.0

Comment: I'd guess that it's due to the overhead involved in calling a function (new scope/context) for each array item. For me, the native functions are so fast (e.g. 74 million ops/sec for array.some) that users aren't going to see a difference and the time saved not writing/maintaining my own function is worth it.

Comment: Most of the tests are flawed because they're just doing different things (e.g. `concat` creating a new array vs. `push` adding to an existing one). Also your `find` test is fundamentally broken with its `return` statement outside of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless js is parsed and we never know what the actual executed machine code looks like, its probably a good way of checking the efficiency of a high level algorithm to transpile it to assembly.

1) a regular for loop:

```
loop:
  CP A,100 //the exit statement
  JP z,end // exit

  LD A,123//some random math
  LD B,124
  ADD A,B
  LD 123,A

  JP loop //the actual loop     

end:
```

2) a prototype function:

```
Array_forEach:
loop:
  CP A,B //the exit statement
  JP z,end // exit

  LD 123,A//remove values from direct registers
  LD 124,B

  LD arg1,array_length //prepare function environment
  LD arg2,A

  CALL anonymous_func

  LD A,123
  LD B,124

  JP loop //the actual loop

anonymous_func:
  LD A,123//some random math
  LD B,124
  ADD A,B
  LD 123,A
  RET
```

As you can see, the forEach uses some expensive *CALL*s, not to mention the context change.

---

However, the parser may not even let both run that deep level, or it does some really good inlining, meaning that forEach actually runs faster than a for loop sometimes.